# each item wise count with conditions

Tags: oracle

I have 2 columns job and department in the table emp.

```
job                   department
-------------------------------------------
manager              accounting
president            accounting
manager              accounting
clerk                accounting
manager              accounting
manager              accounting
manager              accounting
clerk                accounting
analyst              accounting
security             accounting
security             accounting
clerk                accounting
analyst              accounting
security             accounting
```

I have a requirement to pull the data like below

```
status       status_numbers        status2           status_numbers2            outstanding                     total
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
manager             5              manager               14                 total-status_numbers2               14
president           1              president             9                  total-status_numbers2               14 
clerk               3              clerk                 8                  total-status_numbers2               14
analyst             2              analyst               5                  total-status_numbers2               14
security            3              security              3                  total-status_numbers2               14
```

In status_numbers2 column we need to pull the data in below fashion
for manager
o   Sum  of  manager, president, clerk, analyst, security from the progress_cmc_status_numbers field(14)

for president 
 sum of president, clerk, analyst, security from the progress_cmc_status_numbers field(9)

for clerk
sum of clerk, analyst, security from the progress_cmc_status_numbers field(8)

for analyst
sum of analyst, security from the progress_cmc_status_numbers field(5)

for security
sum of security from the progress_cmc_status_numbers field(3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select status ,status_numbers, SUM(status_numbers) OVER (ORDER BY ordr desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) status_numbers2
from
(
select "job" status, count(*) status_numbers , decode("job", 'manager', 1, 'president',2, 'clerk', 3,'analyst', 4, 'security', 5) ordr
from emp
group by "job") t
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d7ba/9)

Comment: thanks for the query but i need to get the count 14 for manager (manager+president+clerk+analyst+security) i.e 5+1+3+2+3=14

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments

Comment: Glad to be of some help. If you find this answer helpful, you may consider accepting it http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask